# WPF - Dependency Properties Error

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, attachedbehaviors, custom-properties

I'm working on a WPF project, and my intention is to make two specific RadioButtons alter properties of another specified Component. But for now, i'm just trying to store a String inside the RadioButton.

For that, I've created a behavior class:

```
    public class AdjustBehavior : Behavior<RadioButton>
{
```

With this property:

```
        public static DependencyProperty AdjustLabelContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LabelContent", typeof(String), typeof(AdjustBehavior),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```

And these getters and setters:

```
       public static String GetLabelContent(RadioButton tb)
    {
        return (String)tb.GetValue(AdjustLabelContentProperty);
    }

    public static void SetLabelContent(RadioButton tb, String value)
    {
        tb.SetValue(AdjustLabelContentProperty, value);
    }
```

On the XAML side, I did this:

```
    <RadioButton Content="Banana" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,216,0,0" Name="radioButton1" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="a" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="True" Checked="radioButton1_Checked" >
        <int:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <i:AdjustBehavior LabelContent="Apple" />
        </int:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </RadioButton>
```

Where int: is the namespace to Interaction.Behaviors and i: is the namespace to the AdjustBehavior class. But whenever I start my application, LabelContent is set to null. Why?

I didn't post the rest of my Behavior class because I think it won't matter, but I'll do if necessary.

Thanks in Advance.

Clark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attached property requires target to be attached to. In your case that target is radio button,
so you should use

```
<RadioButton i:AdjustBehavior.LabelContent="Apple" ... />
```

If you need to just create property of AdjustBehavior, use normal dependency property, not attached.

Answer (score 1):

You should use DependencyProperty.Register, not RegisterAttached.  This isn't being used as an attached property, but rather a standard dependency property.

Answer (score 0):

LabelContent should be either an attached property on RadioButton or dependency property on AdjustBehavior .